# Can we write jquery in XML Code, I am trying to call Bootstrap modal popup by clicking the svg image

Tags: jquery, xml, html, svg

Below is the code for example,

its working fine in local, but not working in live and  showing the below error: **XML Parsing Error: junk after document element**

please look into below code, please let me know how fix this issue.

```
<image x="0" y="0" width="2px" height="2px" xlink:href="../multimedia/SVGIcons/PNG/72-DPI/assets_icn_action_email_normal.png">
</image>

<style type="text/css">
    .st0{fill:#505252;}
    .st1{fill:#C2C6C9;}
    .st2{fill:#3B87DE;}
    .st3{fill:#191A00;}
    .st4{fill:#D6D7D6;}
    .st5{fill:#D6D7D6;stroke:#D6D7D6;stroke-miterlimit:10;}
    .st6{fill:#FFFFFF;}
    .st7{fill-rule:evenodd;clip-rule:evenodd;fill:#D6D7D6;}
    .st8{fill:none;stroke:#FFFFFF;stroke-miterlimit:10;}
    .st9{fill:#4E7EA7;}
    .st10{fill:none;stroke:#191A00;stroke-width:2;stroke-miterlimit:10;}
    .st11{fill:none;stroke:#D6D7D6;stroke-width:2;stroke-miterlimit:10;}
    .st12{fill:none;stroke:#666666;stroke-miterlimit:10;}
    .st13{fill:none;stroke:#3B87DE;stroke-miterlimit:10;}
    .st14{fill:none;stroke:#191A00;stroke-miterlimit:10;}
    .st15{opacity:0.5;}
    .st16{fill:#666666;}
    .st17{fill:#4983C3;}
    .st18{fill:#EEF0F2;}
    .st19{fill:none;stroke:#FFFFFF;stroke-width:2;stroke-miterlimit:10;}
    .st20{fill:none;stroke:#BCC3C6;stroke-miterlimit:10;}
    .st21{fill:none;stroke:#3B87DE;stroke-width:1.5;stroke-miterlimit:10;}
    .st22{fill:none;stroke:#4E7EA7;stroke-width:1.5;stroke-miterlimit:10;}
    .st23{fill:#221F1F;}
    .st24{fill:#C2C5C9;}
    .st25{fill:#DE1E35;}
    .st26{fill:#F49E1D;}
    .st27{fill:#DC1E35;}
    .st28{fill:none;stroke:#646B74;stroke-miterlimit:10;}
  image{cursor:pointer}
</style>
</svg>
<script src="../client_asset/dist/js/jquery.1.11.3.min.js">,</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
  $("svg image").click(function(){
  alert("test");
  });
})
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a comma in your jquery script tag that may be throwing an exception/error:

```
<script src="../client_asset/dist/js/jquery.1.11.3.min.js">,</script>
                                                        // ^ here
```

Try removing it and check if it works.